# Ifstream code is not placing the input into the variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, ifstream, ofstream, iomanip

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //variable init
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    string toPrint, fileName;
    string var;
    cout << "Enter your save file: "; cin >> fileName;//asks the file name
    cout << "Searching..."<<endl;

    string fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\CraftedGaming\\Documents\\" + fileName + ".txt";//locates it
    inFile.open(fileLocation.c_str());
    if(!inFile){//checks if the file is existent
        cerr << "Error can't find file." << endl;
        outFile.open(fileLocation.c_str());
        outFile << "Player House: Kubo"<<endl;
        outFile.close();
    }
    cout << "Loaded." << endl;

    inFile.ignore(1000, ':'); inFile >> var; //gets the string and places it in variable named var
    cout << var<<endl;

    //replaces var
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> var;

    //saving
    outFile.open(fileLocation.c_str());
    outFile << "Player House: " << var;
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
}
```

Problem here is that I can't get the player's house named "Kubo" and place it in variable named "var". It manages to create the file in my documents and manages to change the variable in the replaces var section.

Comment: Opening the same file twice at the same time is fraught with peril.

Comment: Not really. I did this and had no effect on my previous files. Besides I didn't reopen any files.

Comment: You don't close `inFile` before you open `outFile`,  You also don't check if opening `outFile` succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you need to simultaneously read and write a file. Try this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string fileName;
    cout << "Enter your save file: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    string filePath = "C:\\Users\\CraftedGaming\\Documents\\" + fileName + ".txt";
    fstream file(filePath, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);   // open modes to read and write simultaneously
    string var;
    if (file.tellg() == 0)
        file << "Player House: Kubo\n";
    file.seekg(14);
    file >> var;
    cout << var << endl;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I used `tellg()` to determine whether file is empty, you could also go with

```
file.peek() == ifstream::traits_type::eof();
```

Comment: Two errors shown on line 16
1. Error (active) more than one operator "==" matches these operands:.....
2. Error C2666 'std::fpos<_Mbstatet>::operator ==': 3 overloads have similar conversions

Comment: @CraftedGaming works for me [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5998c73b5bd42f51)

Comment: What IDE are you using? I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I tried using file.peek() it ran but it just gave me a blank screen after inputting the file name.

Comment: [Coliru Online Compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) based on g++. You can reach through link in previous comment.

Comment: `if(file.tellg() == static_cast<std::streampos>(0))` on Visual Studio 2015.